# Mysql - Filter a list of degrees in a table range

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, 360-degrees

So, I have a mysql table with ranges of degrees and I should do a query with another range of degrees.

Currently I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM degrees WHERE 
  start_date = '2017-01-01' AND finish_date = '2018-01-01'
  AND (
    (0.51797199999999 BETWEEN begin_degree AND end_degree) 
    OR (2.836271 BETWEEN begin_degree AND end_degree)
    OR (6.953746 BETWEEN begin_degree AND end_degree)
    OR (9.684033 BETWEEN begin_degree AND end_degree)
    OR (13.877806 BETWEEN begin_degree AND end_degree)
    ...
  )
```

The problem is there is millions of rows in this degree table and each query has more or less 200 OR statements. Because of that the query is taking 7-8 seconds to run and I have to do more 10 others similar queries by request.

So, anyone know a better/faster way to do query?
I also created indexes to start_date, finish_date, begin_degree and end_degree.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something strange about this table.  Can you explain why it is structured that way?

Comment: @RickJames. Sure. I have events that can occur in many degrees between 0 and 360 with 6 decimals numbers of precision. And I have to return this events for specifics degrees (208 degrees approximately) in a period. Because of that we structured the table to store ranges of positions/events.

Comment: Is one of them always 13.877806?  Do the values of `begin_degree` and `end_degree` change from time to time?  There are two hard-to-optimize things: `OR` and `BETWEEN col1 AND col2`; I am trying to devise a technique to avoid one or both.

Comment: An aside...  On the earth, 6 decimal places is enough GPS precision to distinguish my two shoulders.  Do you really have that much precision?

Comment: @RickJames, you are right. We create ranges considering only 3 decimal places, but store the full 6 decimal places. What do you think in put this 200 where degrees to a temp table and do a join table? is OR conditions in WHERE clauses slower than JOIN tables?

Comment: @RickJames, about what you said before. The row will never change, it's read only. What can happen is add new ranges for new dates. And no, its no always be the same values they'll vary for each query.

Comment: What is the typical diff between `begin_degree` and `end_degree`?  Do they add up to only a small fraction of 360 degrees?  Do they overlap?

Comment: Hi @RickJames. Yes, they can overlap. For example, I can have an event that occurs in degree 100 every month. And when I search for a year, it'll return 12 events to the same degree. About the diff. It's a range and precision, we do not have to store every degree with his decimal difference (we think it'll have many rows that will never be used, what do you think?), because of that we created a range that we can control the precision and decrease the number of rows.

Comment: "In degree" -- Does that mean 100.00 to 101.00?  If they are all that way, we _may_ be about to do something with there being only 360 choices instead of arbitrary FLOAT ranges.  Sometimes it is a tradeoff between speed and space.  And, in databases, sometimes an INDEX can significantly help deal with "space".

Comment: Sorry @RickJames, I didn't explain well... I can have an event that occurs at degree 100.123456 every month, and can be other degree too. Depending on event type the float precision can be different. that is the reason we don't store every degree position. Currently we are using 3 decimal places, but we store all 6 decimal places because our webservice return in that way.

Comment: Please provide a sample pair of begin/end_degree values.  Something to note:  the constant `2.836271` is unlikely to match the `FLOAT` value `2.836271`.  This is because _constant_ will be rendered in `DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that 7-8 seconds this query isn't so bad.  My one suggestion is an index on `(start_date, finish_date begin_degree, end_degree)`.  That might help performance.

Comment: thanks for reply. so, I already have this index, and another one only with `(start_date, finish_date)`, and mysql prefer do not use `(start_date, finish_date begin_degree, end_degree)`.

Comment: That's because `OR` is essentially optimizable.  And the _narrower_ index is preferred when the extra columns are useless.